# Cómo configurar un Data Store apntando a MySQL Server en un Genexus 17U8 sin que de error?

Tags: genexus

Tenemos una KB desarrollada sobre un Genexus 17 Upgrade 8. La misma utiliza ".Net Framework Enviroment"(C# para el Backend); y por consiguiente generó por default los Data Stores bajo "SQL Server".
Ahora necesitamos cambiar, hacer un "Change Data Store" para pasar de SQL Server a MySQL.
Ya en en la notebook que utilizamos para desarrollar tenemos instalado un MYSQL Server 8.0.29 donde tenemos las base de datos a las cuales queremos que el Genexus acceda.
Tambien, siguiendo el link
https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?2041,MySQL%20driver%20for%20.NET%20installation

Descargamos e instalamos los conectores

- el MySQLDriverCS 4.0.1 …………descargado de   https://sourceforge.net/projects/mysqldrivercs/files/MySQLDriverCS-n-EasyQueryTools/Release%204.0.1/
- el Connector/NET 8.0.29 …………… descargado de https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Una vez listo, todo esto cuando intentamos hacer el "Change Data Store"  y en propiedades dejamos:
-Access technology to set = ADO.NET
-ADO.NET provider: probamos tanto con "MySQLDriverCS" como con "MySQL Conector"

Al querer confirmar los cambios en la Conexión, arroja el siguiente error:

---

### Connection failed to localhost.
If you need to install MySQL server visit http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.0.html#win32

## Product = GeneXus 17
Version = 17.0.158023 U8

### MySQLDriverCS Exception: MySQLDriverCS Error: can't connect.Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client (MySQLDriverCS)

Program Location:
at MySQLDriverCS.MySQLConnection.Open()
at Artech.ReverseEngineering.Data.DBConnection.Connect()

---

Qué paso mas debemos hacer para lograr establecer la conexion a las bases de datos de MySQL Server 8.0.29?

Desde ya muchas gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**05-jul-2022 **>>
Aun modificando el valor de la propiedad da el mismo error. Lo que no llego a entender es porque si tengo instalado en mi notebook de desarrollo el MySQL Server 8.0.29 con el correspondiente conector 8.0.29, el mensaje de error sugiere que instalemos el MySQL y pone un limk que dice 5.0 ...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

En las propiedades del DataStore, tenes que poner compatibilidad con MySQL 8.
Especificamente en la propiedad "MySQL version" setear el valor: "8.x or higher".

Comment: he actualizado la publicacion. Probé cambiar la propiedad por el valor correcto en funcion al MySQL Server que tengo instalado en mi notebook pero sigue el mismo error

Comment: en ADO.NET Provider proba en dejar la propiedad default. Luego parate sobre el datastore > edit connection y ahi proba de conectar con tu usuario root y password. Crea la bd desde ahi a ver si te permite o te da otro error.

Answer (score 0):

La origen del problema és la configuraciones del usuário en MySQL.

Mira esto link.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-navigator-management-users-and-privileges.html

Tiene que cambiar la forma de encriptación o añadir más informaciones en String Connection.

Comment: Luis, estoy utilizando el usuario "root" con el cual puede y puedo establecer conexión sin problemas desde el "MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE". El problema es que no puedo establecer la conexion desde el Data Stores del Genexus 17U8 porque da el error